# invalid_grant Code was already redeemed

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-authentication

I have a PHP application which is managing Google calendar entries. Its installed on two of my sites.

On the first site, it has been running for about a year, no problems and the sync is maintained.

On the other site however (different Google account), I keep seeing the error...

```
Invalid token formatarray (
  'error' => 'invalid_grant',
  'error_description' => 'Code was already redeemed.',
)
```

Been trying to figure this out for weeks now with no joy. Here are some snippets of my code (used within WordPress)...

```
$this->auth  = get_option( 'google_calendar_auth_code' ); // API Setting
$this->token = get_transient( 'google_calendar_token' );

$this->client = new Google_Client();
$this->client->setApprovalPrompt( 'force' );
$this->client->setAccessType( 'offline' );
$this->client->setApplicationName( 'MY_APP' );
$this->client->setClientId( '*****.apps.googleusercontent.com' );
$this->client->setClientSecret( '******' );
$this->client->setRedirectUri( 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' );
$this->client->setScopes( array( 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly' ) );

try {
    $this->calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar( $this->client );
} catch( Google_Service_Exception $e )  {
    error_log( 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() );
}

if ( ! empty( $this->token ) )  {

    $this->client->setAccessToken( $this->token );

} else  {

try {

    $access_token = $this->client->authenticate( $this->auth );

} catch( Exception $e ) {

    error_log( 'Unable to connect to calendar. ' . $e->getMessage() );

    return false;

}

if ( $access_token )    {

    try {
        $this->client->setAccessToken( $access_token );
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        error_log( 'Access token error. ' . $e->getMessage() . var_export( $access_token, true ) );
        return false;
    }

    set_transient( 'google_calendar_token', $access_token, 0 );

    $redirect = admin_url( 'edit.php' );

    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect );
    exit;

    } else  {
        return false;
    }

    $this->token = json_decode( $this->client->getAccessToken() );

    if ( ! defined( 'GOOGLE_TOKEN' ) )  {
        define( 'GOOGLE_TOKEN', true );
    }

    return true;

}
```

I'm clearly not refreshing the token correctly or something but I cannot figure it out.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that you are trying to use an access code that was already used (like how the message describes). When you request authorization, you are given an access code, something similar to this **4/UpUXsWcYumk8bdK7GtMm81WeeWpuPvhwsOrgbWU**. This can only be used once to obtain a refresh token and an access token. Afterwards, you use only the refresh token to get a new access token every time the access token expires. What you need to do is go through the authorization flow again to get a new access code and hence a new refresh token and access token.

I recommend you to play with the OAUth 2.0 Playground [right here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Although, base on your code. I think your problem is here:

```
try {

$access_token = $this->client->authenticate( $this->auth );

}
```

You see, when you **authenticate**, you have to provide the access code returned by the authentication URL. Since that part is done, you don't have to authenticate the user again, instead you just need to refresh the access token. So your flow should be something like this:

```
if ( ! empty( $this->token ) )  {

    $this->client->setAccessToken( $this->token );

} else  {

    this->client->refreshToken(this->refreshToken); 
    this->client->setAccessToken(this->client->getAccessToken());

}
```

Instead of using `$this->auth  = get_option( 'google_calendar_auth_code' );` you can use `$this->refreshToken= get_option( 'google_refresh_token' );`.

Just please note: I'm not saying "this is the way it should be" but I hope it can give you an idea. Hope it helps!

Comment: This has been done. Even to the degree of removing the application from the authorised list of applications from the users account and then going through the auth process again.
Also once auth is complete, we can manage entries for a short period before seeing the invalid_grant error

Comment: @Mike Ahh! I see now. In that case I strongly believe you are not refreshing the token properly. I have updated my answer.